# Implementing a delay function using setTimeout() with passing optional arguments (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get to grips with Javascript by implementing intermediate functions from scratch. Currently trying to implement a delay function that executes an arbitrary function passed as an argument after a waiting time (wait). This also needs to be able to forward additionally passed arguments as extra arguments for the function being delayed.

What I have made so far isn't calling the function within the setTimeout(). Im not sure if its a syntax error or ive just missed the point completely. I have looked through similar questions on here and tried to implement some of the suggested results, however none seem to take the additional arguments aspect into consideration. Anyway, here is what I currently have.

```
    var exampleDelay = function (func, wait) {
      return function () {
        setTimeout(func.apply(this, arguments), wait);
      }
    };
```

Any help tackling this would be appreciated (or if anyone can point me to an answer I may have missed).

Comment: `exampleDelay` is a function, you've to call it before the timeout can be executed.

Comment: Do you know that setTimeout accepts more than two arguments? Would that help?

Comment: `func.apply(this, arguments)` calls `func` immediately - perhaps you meant `setTimeout(func.bind(this), wait, ...arguments);`

Comment: I call exampleDelay later on down the line in a test scenario with a simple function that adds to a counter each time it is called (just to see if it works).

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. `var exampleDelay = window.setTimeout;`?

Comment: Note: it's a little more complex in old javascript `setTimeout.apply(undefined, [func.bind(this), wait].concat(arguments));`

Comment: Jaromanda X: thanks for the input, still unsuccessful though. You say that apply calls the function immediately; does it still do this even when invoked within setTimeout()?

Answer (score 1):

Fran beat me to it but just for variety.
if you want to supply all the params at once this might be an option

```js
   var exampleDelay = function(callback,wait,args) {
   
var args = [].slice.call(arguments) // get the parent arguments and convert to an array
args.splice(0,2); // remove the first two argument which are the fuction supplied and the wait time

// a fuction to call the supplied function
    var callnow =  function() {  
    var params = arguments; // get the child arguments 
    var context = this;
    
    setTimeout(function(){
      callback.apply(context, params) // call the function 
    }, wait);
  }
     
     callnow.apply( this, args ) // use apply to supply the arguments extracted from the parrent
   };


   exampleDelay(console.log, 1000,"hey")

   exampleDelay(console.log, 5,"hey", "there")
```

```
 callnow.apply( this, args ) // we then call the function with apply and supply args extracted from the parent
```

well, you can handle function validation later to make sure that the first argument is a function

Answer (score 0):

The function you return from `exampleDelay` is the one you call later one.
To preserve the `arguments` at the time of calling that function until the time the timer executes it you can wrap the intended function in an anonymous function within the timer. Then inside you can use `apply` to pass the previously stored arguments. Similar to the below.

```js
var exampleDelay = function(func, wait) {
  return function() {  
    var params = arguments;
    var context = this;
    
    setTimeout(function(){
      func.apply(context, params)
    }, wait);
  }
};

var func1 = function(a, b) {
  console.log(a + b);
}

var func2 = function(a, b, c) {
  console.log(a, b, c);
}

var x = exampleDelay(func1, 1000);
var y = exampleDelay(func2, 2000);

x(12, 15);
y('How', 'Are', 'You?');
```